# How to write cross database query in entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am using entity framework 6.1 and I have two databases.

1. `CustomerDB`
2. `CustomerArchiveDB`

Both have a `Customer` table with columns `Name, Address, Year` etc.

I want to get all the customers from both databases using Entity Framework.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can't you query the first db then change your connection string then query the second db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 EF models, one for each database. Materialize the objects with ToList or ToArray from each DbContext and then Concat them together in memory.

Comment: both the tables have crores of data, with your approach i have to load all the data in-memory and then perform operation. which would be slow.

Comment: The problem is that one EF model can't use 2 connection strings and  multiple models can't use joins. Perhaps you can tackle the problem on a lower level in the db itself by creating a view to the archived customers in your active db? Or even a joined view of both the customers tables.